# Looping over dictionary and append list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dataframe, dictionary

I have over 100 lists to make.
How can I make just one and then loop over them?
It is more complex than the usual dictionary looping.

```
list(i)=[]
for a in dict(i)['a']:
    d={}
    d['A']=string
    list(i).append(d)
list(i) = pd.DataFrame(list(i))
list(i)['Link'] = df['link'][i-1]
list(i)['Caption'] = df['caption'][i-1]
list(i)['Family_Type']=df['family_type'][i-1]
list(i)['Product_Type']=df['product_type'][i-1]
list(i).to_excel('list'+str(i).xlsx')

Variable Types:
print(type(dict1)) --> dict
print(type(dict1['a'])) --> list
print(type(string)) --> str
print(type(list1)) --> list
```

Edit tried code:

```
d2 = {}
for i in range(1,100):
    d["list{0}".format(i)]=[]
        for i in range(1, 100):
            d["list{0}".format(i)] = comment.text
            d["list{0}".format(i).append(d2)
    d["list{0}".format(i)] = pd.DataFrame(d["list{0}".format(i)])
    d["list{0}".format(i)]['Link'] = df['link'][i-1]
    d["list{0}".format(i)]['Caption'] = df['caption'][i-1]
    d["list{0}".format(i)]['Family_Type'] = df['family_type'][i-1]
    d["list{0}".format(i)]['Product_Type'] = df['product_type'][i-1]
    d["list{0}".format(i)].to_excel('list'+str(i).xlsx')
```

returns an error

Comment: Just write a `for` loop and put one copy of your code inside it.

Comment: please take a look at the revised edit. I have problem with the complex loop.

Comment: look at your code: 2 times `for i in` and bad indenting, ever wandered to extract `"list{0}".format(i)` into a variable. `d["list{0}".format(i).append(d2)` is illegal python, do you want to share the same dict `d2` in all cases

Comment: sorry, but that's my best effort so far as a beginner. Please suggest a revision.

Comment: You have a problem because you use the same `i` variable to mean two different things.  Use meaningful variable names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i,_ in enumerate(df['link'], 1):
    listi = pd.DataFrame( [{'A':string} for a in locals()[f"dict{i}"]['a'] ] )
    listi['Link']=df['link'][i-1]
    listi['Caption']=df['caption'][i-1]
    listi['Family_Type']=df['family_type'][i-1]
    listi['Product_Type']=df['product_type'][i-1]
    listi.to_excel(f'list{i}.xlsx')
```